# sprintf leading zero padding in C

Tags: c, printf

The code below prints `ffffffffff`.

I need to the output to be 16 digits long `000000ffffffffff` with leading zeros. The `var1` and `var2` variables can be different so it is not necessary that I want to pad 6 zeros only. I just need to output to be 16 digits with leading zeros. How should I proceed?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int var1 = 1048575;
    int var2 = 1048575;

    char buffer[100];

    sprintf(buffer, "%x%x", var1, var2);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ is not C is not C++!

Comment: `%016X` should work...

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two steps:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int var1 = 1048575;
    int var2 = 1048575;
    int length = 0;
    char buffer[100];
    char paddedbuffer[100] = "000000000000000";
    length = sprintf (buffer, "%x%x", var1, var2);
    char* here = length < 16 ? paddedbuffer + 16 - length : paddedbuffer;
    sprintf(here, "%s", buffer);
    printf("%s\n", paddedbuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

There's probably a more elegant solution somewhere.

Another possibility is converting your result into an integer and `sprintf`ing that with a field width, or calculating the actual digits of the rightmost number first.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int var1=1048575;
    int var2=1048575;

    char buffer [17];
    char zeros [] = "0000000000000000";    
    sprintf (buffer, "%x%x", var1, var2);

    // Put the zeros in front
    int len = strlen(buffer);
    if (len < 16)
    {
        zeros[16-len] = 0x0; // Terminate the string at 16-len
    }
    else
    {
        zeros[0] = 0x0;  // Terminate the string at 0 as no extra zero is needed
    }

    printf("%s%s\n", zeros, buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `zeros` array contains one `'0'` (the digit) and 16 zeros (the number), so you will pad the output with at most one digit. ( [Test of your solution](http://ideone.com/w7HbbF).)

Comment: @molbdnilo - ups, I was a little to fast there. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution without an intermediary buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int var1 = 1048575;
    int var2 = 1048575;

    printf("%0*x%x\n", 16 - snprintf(NULL, 0, "%x", var2), var1, var2);

    return 0;
}
```

There is a special case for which you might want to define the precise behavior: what if `var2 == 0`? The above code will print a trailing `0`. If you want only significant digits printed, and therefore no digits for a zero value, you can modify the statement this way:

```
    printf("%0*x%x\n", 16 - snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.x", var2), var1, var2);
```

A small difference: adding a `.` between `%` and `x` to specify a precision field of `0` specifying the minimum number of digits as none.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do some small calculus to compute the number of significant digits and then print the desired number of leading zeros as log_base_ 16(var) is the size of var in hexadecimal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int var1 = 1048575;
    int var2 = 1048575;
    int padd = 16 - ceil(log(var1)/log(16))-ceil(log(var2)/log(16));
    char buffer [100];
    sprintf (buffer, "%0*x%x%x", padd, 0, var1, var2);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another slight twist using a *tmp* buffer and a string (char array) of `'0'`s:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { PADLN = 16, MAXC = 17 };

int main (void)
{
    int var1=1048575;
    int var2=1048575;

    char tmp [MAXC];
    char buffer [MAXC];
    char zeros[] = "0000000000000000";
    size_t len = 0;

    sprintf (tmp, "%x%x", var1, var2);
    len = strlen(tmp);
    zeros[PADLN - (len < PADLN ? len : PADLN)] = 0;
    sprintf (buffer, "%s%s", zeros, tmp);

    printf ("\n buffer : '%s'\n\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/pad16

 buffer : '000000ffffffffff'
```

Answer (score 0):

Print `var2` and then print the concatenation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int var1 = 1048575;
  int var2 = 1048575;

  char buffer[100];
  char bufvar2[sizeof var2 * CHAR_BIT + 1];
  int len = sprintf(bufvar2, "%x", var2);

  #define TOTAL_MIN_WIDTH 16
  sprintf(buffer, "%0*x%s", TOTAL_MIN_WIDTH - len, var1, bufvar2);
  printf("%s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```